# Checkbox is Always being checked

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, input, checkbox

I have a checkbox

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="Vebasto" class="checkbox" value="350" id="Vebasto" />
    <label for="Vebasto">Vebasto</label>
```

And script that checks if it checked:

```
  if(document.querySelector('input#cond').checked = true){
    alert("checked");
    }
```

When page is loading I have got this alert but checkbox in not checked. What's wrong?

Comment: Apart from the error with the _assignment_ operator as mentioned in other answers, `input#cond` would not seem to target the checkbox in question? (Why not use `getElementById()` in this instance?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use === in an if statement:

```
  if(document.querySelector('input#cond').checked === true){
    alert("checked");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the `=` operator is used to atribute a value. So you were actually setting the checkbox value to True.
To compare you should use `==` or even better `===`

```
if(document.querySelector('input#cond').checked === true){
  alert("checked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wanna test something with if() you don't use =., You use ==.
and when its Javascript you its better to use ===

Your code should be.

```
if(document.querySelector('input#cond').checked === true){
alert("checked");
}
```

But the way i go for testing a boolean is simply

```
if(document.querySelector('input#cond').checked) {
alert("checked");
}
```